# Blend file huge, but everything is pink

Tags: texturing

I have a starship model that I have got from a well respected modeller. The file is over 1GB, so I assume it contains textures. However, everything is pink. What could I do to try to find out if the textures are included in the .blend file or not?

Comment: You could try File > External Data >Report Missing Files in Blender then Window > Toggle System Console should show any missing files.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct you can check the textures in the image editor, you can click there: [image]

There should be the list of every textures in the file like this: [image]

if it's empty, then the textures are missing and the file size is due to a lot of geometry in the mesh I guess, but if the textures are there, maybe blender cannot find them due to a change of path or you might need to reassign them to the mesh.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: That's not completely correct. If there are _Image Texture_ nodes in materials that have the name of the missing textures stored, then these texture names will show up in the image list of the _Image Editor_ (or the _UV Editor_ as well), but most likely it will show an empty thumbnail (although in the material slot the preview sometimes is still there) and if you click on it to see it, the image editor window will stay empty. But seeing the names in the list is no indicator is the textures are missing.

Comment: I have checked that, of course. The texture previews show as empty, as they do when I open them in blender's image editor. I suppose the textures are in there somewhere though, because there's absolutely not 1GB worth of geometry in the file.